# Diagram showing the place where the wine offerings of the whole year collected and its relationship to the altar in the Temple

Tags: beis-hamikdash, grapes-wine, pictures, masechet-sukkah, mizbeach-altar

[Gemoro Sukkah 49a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.49a.4?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) refers to the “shittin”.

In the Temple, there was a a narrow shaft that was formed on the west side of the gap between the ramp and the altar.

Rashi on 'בין כבש למזבח' says:

> אויר יש בין כבש למזבח ואותו אויר קרוי בין כבש למזבח ולול היה באותו
> אויר במערבו של כבש בשמונה אמות מערבית של כבש שהכבש רחבו ט"ז אמה ממזרח
> למערב ואותו חלל שהנסכים יורדין לתוכו שהן נעשין בדרומית מערבית של מזבח
> ומוקף ארבע מחיצות עד קרקעיתו וקרקעיתו של רצפת שיש ואין היין נבלע שם
> וכל נסכי יין של כל השנה יורדין שם
>
> There was a space between the ramp and the altar and that space was
> called  בין כבש למזבח. And there was a לול in that space on the west
> side of the ramp in the 8 western amos of the ramp. Because the ramp
> as 16 amos from east to west and the space into which the wine
> offerings went down was on the western side of the altar and enclosed
> by four partitions to the ground level which was marble. The wine was
> not absorbed there and all the wine offerings of the whole year went
> down there.

I cannot picture the relationship between the space between the ramp and the altar and the לול below.

Is there a diagram that can clarify it for me please?

Answer (score 6):

Yes if you look at the Perush Chai [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47554&st=&pgnum=135) it has a clear diagram:

[image]

In addition, the Machon Hamikdash website features a write up on both the [שיתין](https://www.temple.org.il/single-post/2016/12/27/-d7-a9-d7-99-d7-aa-d7-99-d7-9f) and the [לול](https://www.temple.org.il/single-post/2017/07/16/-d7-9c-d7-95-d7-9c-2) with artistic renderings which might perhaps provide further context and visualisation.

Comment: Well done for finding the Peirush Chai. 
My question related to the space between the ramp and the altar and the לול below. 
I don't see that space nor the  לול in the diagrams. 
In 643, what is the black square on the right hand side of the diagram and how does the person get into position to catch the wine going to the shittin?

Comment: Did you take a look at the link to see the earlier picture?

Comment: Yes. It didn't help me nor my chavrusa.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok - please note I added another link which may help you to visualise it further.

Comment: Thank you indeed.